# Passing information from forms and your own information

Tags: php, mysql

How do I pass information from my form plus some additional data when submitted the form. For 
example if I am using PHP

I have a form and I set the method to GET; now all the fields in the form will be sent in the URL, now suppose if I want to keep a track of how many times the submit is clicked, for that if I pass the variable count along with all the data through URL, how do I do that?

How do I append this data to the existing form's data?

OR suppose if I have a field in my form where I allow to user to enter name of their employs; initially it will show 4 fields for the data, but if I click the submit type button that says MORE, then it will display 4 more fields, and similarly if again he presses more it shows 12,
so I was thinking maybe I could sent a variable $count along with the form data through URL, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's not very clear, you can user $_REQUEST if you want to mix get and post data or use array system in your form. Exemple : <input type="text" name="tab[]"> and you will get an array in $_REQUEST['tab']

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="count" value="50">`

Comment: thanks! @JellyBelly  is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: another way would be to use jQuery to execute the form's submit. Into function jquery you calculate lenght url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would user a hidden field with the "count" value. It will then be passed with all the other form input variables but won't actually be visible to the user on in the form:

```
<input name="field_name" type="hidden" value="cout_value_that_changes" />
```

You can change - Field_name - to what ever you want it to be and the value should be incremented every time the submit button is pressed  - incremented with PHP -
something like:

```
$count++;

value="<?php echo $count;?>"
```

Answer (score -1):

Best solution for your requirement seems Use of JQuery.
Add your fields dynamically using JQuery.
For ref. you may check : http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Without using JQuery, you can have Hidden field which would contain count of the field.
we have to pass count in GET request and while showing field in php, check count field.

Comment: -1: There is no need for client-side scripts here. The `<input type="hidden" />` fields required to do this type of work can easily be added server-side. Using JavaScript for this is the wrong approach and may not work on browsers without javascript. Also, a 31k library just for this is overkill.

Comment: Yes, I agree, javascript is one of the solution, not one and the only solution.

Comment: A solution isn't a solution if it's so convoluted that it will cause you more problems than it actually solves. Adding a `<input type="hidden" />` is trivial. Set to `0` if it doesn't exist, `$_GET['count']++` if it does. Now the JS method: before adding the field, you have to decide if you are going to store your count in a cookie, local storage or other method before even considering adding the field in your form. Since any method you choose won't gracefully degrade, you have to also implement the `<input />` method at which point you realize that you're back at square one.

Comment: it doesnt matter how many hidden elements i pass right?? it's not unconventional to pass ,like two or three hidden parameters?